Updating ADX materialized view backfill effectiveDateTime
We have a materialized view created with backfill and effectiveDateTime = 2024-01-01. Can I alter the materialized view with effectiveDateTime = 2023-01-01? Will the materialized view pull just an additional one year of historical data or will it start again from now() ?

I found my answer. We can't change backfill effective date
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-alter
